# simple php script using 1MB+ memory

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

I have a really simple PHP script here,which simply loads several libraries (6 or 7 small classes) and initialize some variables then generate a very small amount of html code. But seeing from the memory_get_usage() function, I see 1.21MB memory usage.

Is that normal or something is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see what is actually loaded up when you execute PHP use this: [get_defined_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)

The reason PHP is consuming memory may not be your script at all but rather your PHP configuration and other extensions being loaded when php executes.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the libraries. All it takes is one snippet of code to load up your memory. Have you tried to run a code profiler?

Comment: Try Webgrind (or if you are on a linux machine try kcachegrind).